# Add Secondary Sort To Commerce Kickstart Facet Search Product Display

Tags: commerce, search

I have a field in each Product called 'Search-Rank'.

Using the default /Products view, with Facet Sorts by Title and Latest.  When the visitor sorts on Title or Latest I want the view to sort by Title and -then- this Search-Rank.

How can I add a fixed -secondary- sort by another field?

I don't need Search-Rank to be visible as a Sort Option. I just want it to be a secondary term in the SQL Query. Eg.

```
SELECT fields WHERE <facet_filter_fields> ORDER BY <facet_sort_field>, search_rank ASC
```

Adding a Sort to the View disables the Facet Sort. So where does one 'hook' into the SQL Query to add that secondary sort term?

What am I missing?